# What is the convex hull of $ \{t \to e^{-\lambda t} : \lambda >0\}? $

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

What is the convex hull of 
$$
\{t \to e^{-\lambda t} : \lambda >0\}?
$$
(Interpreted as the set of all functions on the above form.)

Reference or argument is great.

Answer (score 4):

By   [Bernstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein's_theorem_on_monotone_functions), the closed convex hull consists precisely of the *completely monotone* functions, i.e., those that satisfy $$(-1)^n{d^n \over dt^n} f(t) \geq 0$$ for all integers $n\ge 0$ and all $t>0$.

If you consider finite convex combinations only, without taking the closure (which is equivalent to integration against probability measures), then the functions you get is just that, functions of the form $\sum c_k \exp(-\lambda_k t)$ with $c_k\ge 0, \sum c_k=1$.